# Transfer value to TAB Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost

I've 4 Activities.

The first Activity is used to input data, the second Activity is the TABs main Activity (extends TabActivity) to declare each tab Activity, and the 3rd and 4th Activity is tab activity.

How can I transfer values from the first Activity to the third and fourth Activity?

Here's my 1st Activity :

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
  EditText inputName;
  EditText inputAddress;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //declaration layout
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    inputAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    //Listening to button event
    btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Starting a new Intent
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainTabActivity.class);


        //Sending data to another Activity
        //THIS IS THE VALUE I WANNA TRANSFER TO TAB ACTIVITY
        nextScreen.putExtra("name", inputName.getText().toString());
        nextScreen.putExtra("address", inputEmail.getText().toString());

        // starting new activity
        startActivity(nextScreen);

      }
    });
  }
}
```

and here's my MainTabActivity :

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maintabresto);


    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, InfoTab.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("info").setIndicator("Info",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.iconinfotab))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MenuTab.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("menu").setIndicator("Menu",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.iconmenutab))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
  }
}
```

and here's my 3rd an 4th activity (i wanna display the value that i transfer before to textview in each activity) :

```
public class InfoTab extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.infotab);

    TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTEST1);
    TextView txtaddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextTEST2);


    //displaying data from previous activity
    //this is didnt work
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    String address = i.getStringExtra("address");

    // Displaying Received data
    //this is didnt work
    txtname.setText(name);
    txtaddress.setText(address);
  }
}
```

can anyone help me??
i've try to do this on firts activity :

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoTab.class);
```

it works!(the value can be transfered to nextactivity, but instead opening the activity on tab, the activity opening individually (not on tab)...

so my goal here, is to transfer value to each tab activity an they're opening below MainTabActivity.

sorry, if my english isnt good.

Comment: is there anyone can help me??

Comment: Is it solved? I am also facing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some little mistake in your code. But I can't figure it out.

Below is my tabActivity's code in which I am doing the same thing you wanted.

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {
    TabHost myTabHost;
    String data1, data2, data3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_tab_activity);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        data1 = i.getStringExtra("Data1");
        data2 = i.getStringExtra("Data2");
        data3 = i.getStringExtra("Data3");

        setTabs();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_tab_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void setTabs() {
        myTabHost = getTabHost();
        addTab(R.string.tab1Txt, R.drawable.video);
        addTab(R.string.tab2Txt, R.drawable.pdf);
        addTab(R.string.tab3Txt, R.drawable.notepad);
        myTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }

    public void addTab(int labelId, int drawableId) {
        Intent tabIntent = null;
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        switch (labelId) {
        case R.string.tab1Txt:
            tabIntent = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
            tabIntent.putExtra("Data", data1);
            break;
        case R.string.tab2Txt:
            tabIntent = new Intent(this, Tab2Activity.class);
            tabIntent.putExtra("Data", data2);
            break;
        case R.string.tab3Txt:
            tabIntent = new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class);
            tabIntent.putExtra("Data", data3);
            break;
        }

        spec = myTabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);
        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        img.setImageResource(drawableId);
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(tabIntent);
        myTabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.